# Is there anyway to access files from usb without mounting it (in a terminal)

Tags: linux

Is there anyway to access files from usb without mounting it (in a terminal)?
copying or accessing files without mounting it!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all: I think it would be better to post this question on "superuser.com", not on "stackoverflow.com" because this is a question about usage of Linux, not about programming for Linux.

In the 1990s there was a tool which allowed you to read FAT-formatted media (floppys and hard disk partitions) under Linux.

The tool was intended for older Linux versions that did not have FAT file system support.

Because today all Linux versions have FAT file system support I think that tool is no longer maintained however the source codes should still be available somewhere!

FAT32 did not exist, yet, the time when this tool was used so the tool only supported FAT12 and FAT16.

To access the media "root" rights are required in any case.